# Angular-js2.0:->Module not found 'angular/core-js'?What this backtick means which covered template?

Tags: angular

module not found '@angular/core','@angular/platform-browser',same with 3rd one!!

```
   import {
  NgModule,
  Component
 } from '@angular/core';
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-   dynamic';
```

@Component({
     selector: 'hello-world',
     template: 
    `<div>
    Hello world
    </div>`

   })

class HelloWorld {
     }

```
 @NgModule({
 declarations: [ HelloWorld ],
 imports: [ BrowserModule ],
 bootstrap: [ HelloWorld ],
 })

 class HelloWorldAppModule {}

 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(HelloWorldAppModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

Backticks define `Template Strings \ Template literals` in TypeScript and ES6.

These do allow `strings` to be multi-line (which is the main reason why Angular2 uses them, I suppose) and to use `string interpolation` features.

Sample for string interpolation:

```
var name = "World";
console.log(`Hello ${name}!`); // Outputs 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: yeah but @philip if we remove backticks from your code then also we get hello world whats the use of it then?

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, there is Template String feature, that says, we can form/concat string with backtick.

```
var name = 'Mustkeem';
var info = `My name is ${name}.`; // My name is Mustkeem.
```

Other important point to consider is, these backtick support for multi line templates.

However you should use Angular's interpolation syntax {{}} instead of ${}. Because angular's interpolation syntax have some merits like you can also use expressions ({{a + b / 2}}) and pipes ({{title | uppercase}}).